# Hibernate option in Juno

Tags: settings, release-juno

I cannot make my computer **hibernate**. I altered the settings so that pressing the power button sends the computer into hibernate mode but when I actually press the button, *nothing happens*. Also, is there any way in which I can add the hibernate option to the drop down menu that appears when I click on the power option?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, the hibernate option in Power panel doesn't work indeed (checked that myself). As it was mentioned [here](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-power/issues/101), it's possible to hibernate your PC via `sudo systemctl hibernate` command, but impossible to do that via the elementary's power control panel. Long story short, after some [discussion](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-power/issues/78) the devs have decided to [remove](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-power/pull/112) Hibernate option from elementary OS.

Answer (score 0):

I simply press the power option in the top right hand corner and select the option "SUSPEND"
this puts the pc into hybernation mode
to restart just press any key and everything reappears

Comment: About the difference between suspend and hibernate modes: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3369/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-suspend

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to add it into the menu dropdown, but I have managed to achieve hibernation and set it on the Lid close. Same way if it works for you, you can add it on the powerbutton hit just by edit the appropriate line according to the last title in my answer there - https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/21812/12483