# How enable hibernation in Elementary Juno?

Tags: laptop

I try with pm-hibernate but don't work. My laptop is Asus Tuf Gaming

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, hibernation does not work in elementary OS, although there is such an option in `System Settings > Power`. For details please see the answer to [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17341/hibernate-option-in-juno/19321#19321).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if they are working on this functionality?

Comment: In a way, they are working on it :)  If you follow the link provided, you'll discover that hibernation mode is probably going to be removed from eOS Power control panel, as it doesn't work anyway.