# Hibernate option in Odin

Tags: wingpanel, power

Question is similar to [Hibernate option in Juno](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17341/hibernate-option-in-juno) but for the Odin.

Does anybody have an instruction how to setting up hibernate mode?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21455/hibernation-on-elementaryos#21915) worked for me. But i am still looking to find a way, to get in hibernation without Terminal.
Also it seems like Hibernation is deactivatet in Ubuntu because it will not work with secure boot.